# How to collect items from one stream into the list and expose the result list via other stream in dart (rxdart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, transform, rxdart

I have a `StreamController`

```dart
final _controller = StreamController<List<LoadedPage<int, Entity>>>.broadcast();
```

and stream which exposes data using similar code:

```dart
void getPagingData() async {
  final response = _api.getData(...);
  final pages = _convertResponseToPadingData(response);
  // This is an example of exposed event:
  // <LoadedPage<int, Entity>>[
  //   LoadedPage(data: <Entity>[...]),
  //   LoadedPage(data: <Entity>[...]),
  //   LoadedPage(data: <Entity>[...]),
  // ]
  _controller.add(pages);
}
```

I need to collect all items from `data` property into the single `List<Entity>` and expose it as a single event via `Stream<List<Entity>>`.

Let say I have a list of 3 loaded pages where each page contains finite number of `Entity` items (for example 30 items). I need to collect all entities from each `page` to a single `List<Entity>` (i.e. 90 items) and expose this list to broadcasted stream.

```dart
Stream<List<Entity> get entities {
  // Here I need an expression which converts Stream<List<LoadedPage<int,Entity>>>
  // to Stream<List<Entity>>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many experiments I found the solution:

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class Page<T> {
  Page({this.data = const []});

  final List<T> data;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Page $data';
}

final pages = <Page<String>>[
  Page(data: ['1', '2', '3']),
  Page(data: ['5', '6', '7']),
  Page(data: ['8', '9', '0']),
];

final _controller = BehaviorSubject<List<Page<String>>>();

void main() async {
  print('Input: $pages');
  final stream = _controller.stream.asyncExpand(
    (pages) => Stream.value(
      pages.fold<List<String>>(
          [], (entities, page) => [...entities, ...page.data]),
    ),
  );
  stream.listen((data) => print('Output: $data'),
      onDone: () => print('Done'), onError: print);
  _controller.add(pages);
}
```

Result is:

```
Input: [Page [1, 2, 3], Page [5, 6, 7], Page [8, 9, 0]]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```